# Execute oracle stored procedure with out cursor from PL/SQL developer

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor, execute, plsqldeveloper

I'm having some troubles executing oracle stored procedure from package.
 I've intalled PL/SQL developer on local machine, and when I try to test procedure I get generated code like this:

```
begin
  -- Call the procedure
  owner.mypackage.getallrequests(res => :res,
                                                        id=> :id);
end;
```

But I can't modify this query to return me data. Would really appreciate help.

Comment: This is not a query it is a PL/SQL block. When you run this in PL/SQL developer or in any other tool it would prompt you for values of `res` and `id`. Enter the values with which you want to test. Should be simple enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've got to this point by right-clicking on the procedure in the object explorer and choosing 'test', you'll have a Test Window with the anonymous PL/SQL block you showed. You haven't said, but I assume `id` is  an `in` variable, and `res` is the `out` cursor variable. In the variable section in the bottom half of the window, type in the ID value you're searching for, then execute it (clicking the gear, or hitting F8).

Nothing obvious will change if those are the only variables; non-cursor `out` or `in out` variables would be highlighted in yellow if their values had changed, but the cursor is not, and `in` variables by definition won't have changed.

At the far right of the `res` cursor variable in the bottom of the test window, there's a small button with `...` in it, which the help pages refer to as the 'cell button'. Click that, and a new window will open showing the cursor result set.

Comment: Thank you, you assumes were right, not usual interface for me.